# How to return array instead of array of object in rails json response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postman

I have a model with the association **download has_many download_links**

I'm calling download_links in the downloadlink controller.

```
  def download_links
    @downloads = Download.all
    render json: { data:@downloads.as_json(:only=>[:id],
    include: {
        :downloadlink => {:only =>:url}
      }
    ), message:"success"}, status: :ok
  end
```

the result in postman is just like this:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "downloadlink": [
            {
                "url": "1920x1080.png"
            },
            {
                "url": "1366x766.png"
            },
            {
                "url": "1280x720.png"
            },
            {
                "url": "1024x768.png"
            }
        ]
    }
],
"message": "success"}
```

now I want a result to be like this:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "downloadlink": [
            "1920x1080.png",
            "1366x766.png",
            "1280x720.png",
            "1024x768.png"
        ]
    }
],
"message": "success"}
```

Comment: My front end wants it. So it is not valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering `download has_many download_links` relation one way of doing it is:

```
def download_links
    @downloads = Download.includes(:download_links)
    render json: { 
       data:@downloads.map{ |d| d.download_json }, message:"success"
    }, status: :ok
  end
```

In **downlad.rb** model

```
has_many :download_links

def download_json
  self.as_json(
    only: [:id],
    methods: [:downloadlink_list]
  )
end

def downloadlink_list
  self.download_links.pluck(:url)
end
```

Correct the name/association as per your naming convention.

Comment: how can i remove the data that has no value?

Comment: {
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "downloadlink_list": [
                "1920x1080.png",
                "1366x766.png",
                "1280x720.png",
                "1024x768.png"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "downloadlink_list": []
        }
}

Comment: I think you should not remove that, just confirm with frontend team, if you remove the attribute it may break at there end because they won't be able to use each loop on it.

Comment: okay sir, thanks, by the way, can you recommend any documentation regarding pluck etc.

Comment: You can refer https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html